# Merge for multiple columns and rows

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data tables:

```
> d1 <- data.table(letter=c("A", "B", "A", "B"), V1=c(0,0,0,0),V2=c(0,0,0,0))
> d2 <- data.table(letter=c("A", "B"), value=c(1,2))
> d1
   letter V1 V2
1:      A  0  0
2:      B  0  0
3:      A  0  0
4:      B  0  0
> d2
   letter value
1:      A     1
2:      B     2
```

I seek to fill columns V1 and V2 from d1 using the values from d2, so that:

```
> d12
   letter V1 V2
1:      A  1  1
2:      B  2  2
3:      A  1  1
4:      B  2  2
```

I assume I have to use the function 'merge' somehow but I have not managed.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setkey(d1, letter)
setkey(d2, letter)
d1[d2, c('V1','V2'):=value]
# d1 holds the updated dt
```

The `d1[d2]` merges d1 to d2; the `c('V1', 'V2'):=value` assigns the `value` column to V1 and V2. rows in `d1` that have letters not in `d2` are left as-is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that the result rearranges the letters alphabetically. How can I avoid this?

Comment: This is the behaviour of `setkey`, and any merge will sort by the key first. If you want to restore the order later you will have to store it first, then restore it e.g. `d1[, order:=1:nrow(order)]` before the `setkey`; then at the end something like `setkey(d1, order)` to order it back at the end. I think `data.table` encourages you not to rely heavily on row order (unless you have some column that encodes that order, which would then form a natural key for the table).